# Using if-statements in PHP to print HTML

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm fairly new to PHP and I've been trying to construct some code to print basic HTML, however the code causes an error 500 whenever used. I am guessing it is a syntax error since I've tried the code in a couple of forms and nothing seems to work (including removing the database lookup and just trying to compare to set values to each other). The script needs to get a variable from the db, compare it to a set value and print the HTML if true, here is the code I am trying:

```
<?php
    $db = &JFactory::getDBO();
    $id = JRequest::getString('id');
    $db->setQuery('SELECT #__categories.title FROM #__content, #__categories WHERE #__content.catid = #__categories.id AND #__content.id = '.$id);
    $category = $db->loadResult(); ?>
  <?php if strcmp($category,"Blog")==0 : ?>

      <div style="display: -webkit-inline-box" class="sharelogos">
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" target="_blank">  <img src="/images/sharing-icons/facebook.png" width="30px" alt="Facebook" /></a>
      </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `if` is incorrect, try like this

```
<?php if (strcmp($category,"Blog")==0) { ?>

      <div style="display: -webkit-inline-box" class="sharelogos">
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" target="_blank">  <img src="/images/sharing-icons/facebook.png" width="30px" alt="Facebook" /></a>
      </div>

<?php } ?>
```